# Xcode TextField Shows Numbers but Code Adds Decimal

Tags: algorithm, textfield

I am making  tip calculator and this is the code I currently have: (Below). [To make it look nice], is there a way for the user to just put in (15), and have code make that say .15 in the background? Thanks

```
- (IBAction)calcTapped:(id)sender {

NSString *billAmountString = [billAmountTextField text];

float billAmountFloat = [billAmountString floatValue];

NSString *tipPercentString = [tipPercentTextField text];

float tipPercentFloat = [tipPercentString floatValue];

float tipAmount = billAmountFloat * tipPercentFloat;

NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tip: %0.2f",

                    tipAmount];
[resultLabel setText:result];
```

}

Comment: also, this isnt about xcode!

Answer (score 1):

Try retrieving the string from the textfield, converting it into a NSNumber (or float) and then dividing by 100. You know, since 15/100 = 0.15.